# C# MaskedTextBox decimal currency not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, currency, maskedtextbox

I am struggling with MaskedTextBox. My mask looks like this:
`R ######.00` to enter South African currency. All still fine. I save the amount to a decimal field, and it is done correctly, with the decimal value and all. The problem is when I try to redisplay the decimal field in the MaskedTextBox. The only way I can get it to display with the decimal value intact is to use:

```
edtBayCost.Text = allParkingBayRegistrationData(currentDisplayRecord).bayCost.ToString("000000.00");
```

In the box it then displays eg. R 001234.56
I have tried replacing the `ToString("000000.00")` with `ToString("######.00")` but then the decimal value is ignored and the display is R 123456.00.

Am I missing something important here?

Comment: Sounds like a Locale/CultureInfo problem

Answer (score -1):

Try using the Currency Format Specifier for the ToString() method:

```
edtBayCost.Text = allParkingBayRegistrationData(currentDisplayRecord).bayCost.ToString("C2");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString

EDIT:

You may also use the Currency Format Specifier with the culture code. This should give you appropriate formatting for the currency you are attempting to use:

```
edtBayCost.Text = allParkingBayRegistrationData(currentDisplayRecord).bayCost.ToString("C3", 
              CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-ZA"));
```

You can use this table as reference for the culture codes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Ee825488(v=CS.20).aspx

Comment: I have tried the ToString("C2"), but the display in the MaskedEdit does not end up the way it's supposed to. If I enter, for instance R100.00, it ends up as R10000_.__ in the box. Really annoying, but I guess I'll have to stick to ToString("000000.00") and live with the zeroes at the front.